# Python console delete key moves the carret like space key

Tags: python, terminal, ansi-escape

Inside of Python console, whenever I press the 'delete' key, a space gets printed on the screen. The buffer however, gets updated correctly it seems.

```
>>> in mport numpi y
```

Here, I type: " in**backspace**mport numpy ". And the interpreter has no issue doing its job.

Any idea what could cause this behavior?

Comment: This is not a Python issue. Check your shell / pseudo-terminal / system settings.

Comment: same issue with multiple terminals